# More than one fragment for pdfs

Tags: java, android, pdf, android-fragments

I am trying to make an app that can render a pdf when someone clicks the specified button. The problem is that whenever  I add another pdf and fragment to render, the software just displays the last one I added and not the others. Here is my code:

**Main activity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View btnRender;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private View btnRendered;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRender = (View)findViewById(R.id.btn_render);
        container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
        btnRendered = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn_rendered);

        //set event handling for button
        btnRender.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
        btnRendered.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {


        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == btnRender) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderFragment());
                    ft.commit();
                    //gone button after all
                    btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (v == btnRendered) {
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderAgment());
                        ft.commit();

                        //gone button after all
                        btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        };
    };



}}
```

**First pdf file**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFRenderFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
    private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
    private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
    private ImageView image;
    private Button btnPrevious;
    private Button btnNext;

    public PDFRenderFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfrender, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Retain view references.
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        btnPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
        btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        //set buttons event
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked

        int index = 0;
        // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
        }
        showPage(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            openRenderer(activity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
            Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            closeRenderer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (null != currentPage) {
            outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDF renderer
     * @param activity
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
        // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
        fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("biology_in_c.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
    }

    /**
     * Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
     */
    private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        pdfRenderer.close();
        fileDescriptor.close();
    }

    /**
     * Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
     * @param index The page index.
     */
    private void showPage(int index) {
        if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }
        // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        //open a specific page in PDF file
        currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
        // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
        currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        // showing bitmap to an imageview
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUIData();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
     */
    private void updateUIData() {
        int index = currentPage.getIndex();
        int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
        btnNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name , index + 1, pageCount));
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
                } else {
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Second pdf file**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.pdf.PdfRenderer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.io.IOException;


public class PDFRenderAgment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor;
    private PdfRenderer pdfRenderer;
    private PdfRenderer.Page currentPage;
    private ImageView image;
    private Button btnPrevious;
    private Button btnNext;

    public PDFRenderAgment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pdfrender, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // Retain view references.
        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        btnPrevious = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_previous);
        btnNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_next);

        //set buttons event
        btnPrevious.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(-1)); //previous button clicked
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(onActionListener(1)); //next button clicked

        int index = 0;
        // If there is a savedInstanceState (screen orientations, etc.), we restore the page index.
        if (null != savedInstanceState) {
            index = savedInstanceState.getInt("current_page", 0);
        }
        showPage(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            openRenderer(activity);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("Fragment", "Error occurred!");
            Log.e("Fragment", e.getMessage());
            activity.finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            closeRenderer();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (null != currentPage) {
            outState.putInt("current_page", currentPage.getIndex());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a PDF renderer
     * @param activity
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void openRenderer(Activity activity) throws IOException {
        // Reading a PDF file from the assets directory.
        fileDescriptor = activity.getAssets().openFd("biology_in_f.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor();

        // This is the PdfRenderer we use to render the PDF.
        pdfRenderer = new PdfRenderer(fileDescriptor);
    }

    /**
     * Closes PdfRenderer and related resources.
     */
    private void closeRenderer() throws IOException {
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        pdfRenderer.close();
        fileDescriptor.close();
    }

    /**
     * Shows the specified page of PDF file to screen
     * @param index The page index.
     */
    private void showPage(int index) {
        if (pdfRenderer.getPageCount() <= index) {
            return;
        }
        // Make sure to close the current page before opening another one.
        if (null != currentPage) {
            currentPage.close();
        }
        //open a specific page in PDF file
        currentPage = pdfRenderer.openPage(index);
        // Important: the destination bitmap must be ARGB (not RGB).
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(currentPage.getWidth(), currentPage.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Here, we render the page onto the Bitmap.
        currentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        // showing bitmap to an imageview
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        updateUIData();
    }

    /**
     * Updates the state of 2 control buttons in response to the current page index.
     */
    private void updateUIData() {
        int index = currentPage.getIndex();
        int pageCount = pdfRenderer.getPageCount();
        btnPrevious.setEnabled(0 != index);
        btnNext.setEnabled(index + 1 < pageCount);
        getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name , index + 1, pageCount));
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onActionListener(final int i) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (i < 0) {//go to previous page
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() - 1);
                } else {
                    showPage(currentPage.getIndex() + 1);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

There are no syntax errors in the program, which leads me to believe that there must be some logical explanation why this doesn't work. If anyone could help that would be much appreciated!

**Edit due to first answer**

That answer did not solve my problem, the last fragment still appeared

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this :
public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {

```
case R.id.btn_render:
    // do your code
    break;

case R.id.btn_rendered:
    // do your code
    break;
default:
    break;
```

}
}

Comment: I didn't add the default...does that make a difference?